# Router keeps disconnecting from the internet

Tags: networking, internet, connection

In our apartment we have 4 computers: two desktops and two laptops, all wirelessly connected through a wireless router (Edimax BR-6226n) connected to a cable modem (Motorola SBV5121).

The problem is, the router keeps disconnecting from the internet very often. Resetting it makes it work again, but it gets disconnected again very quickly - sometimes a matter of minutes.

The router is brand new. The desktops are configured in the OS to recieve static internal ips, and the laptops are configured in the router settings.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you called your ISP?  Do you also have (digital) cable TV?  I would suggest that you get them to run a line test, if only to rule them out as the problem.

Comment: I'll call them if needed, but considering that only reseting my router works for a while, I conclude it's not the modem's fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the problem was uTorrent running on one of the computers. We turned it off and it's working since.

Thanks for the effort, everyone.

Comment: This just shows **the problem is** actually, as expected and surprisingly not mentioned by anyone, **the router** - too weak to handle heavy connection. Even though you mentioned it's new. It's either malfunctioning or quite too cheap.

Comment: @Cawas torrents works in more than 1MB/sec in other computers.

Comment: so you are agreeing with me, right?

Comment: @Cawas no, I meant to say torrents work fine in other computers, so can it be the heavy connection? I suspect it has something to do with high port numbers.

Comment: That's interesting... If it's not heavy load on the router and you think it could be just configuration of ports, then it's a bug in the router. It's still definitely something wrong with it.

Comment: I've seen this before with poor router firmware (specifically buggy UPnP implementations). If you have uTorrent set to use UPnP, see if turning it off makes a difference. Also check the router is not getting too warm and crashing out because mannging connections to running Torrents is too demanding for it.

Irrespective I would also update the firmware on the router in-case the manufacturer has fixed this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest firmware (v1.19)?  You can get it [here](http://www.edimax.co.uk/en/support_detail.php?pd_id=292&pl1_id=3).

It should state which version is currently installed somewhere in its web interface.

Comment: I am using v1.19

Answer (score 0):

I have just remembered that I had the same problem a few years ago, with the modem/router that was suppied by ISP.

If I remember correctly, it turned out to be some sort of incompatibility with an old NIC on one of my computers, which caused the router to continuously crash and reboot and drive me mad.

It was solved (accidentally) when I connected that computer through a switch, rather than directly to the router.

These are LAN-side connection, but it still caused the whole modem/router to crash, which may seem surprising.

Try disconnecting your computers from the router to see if this continues to happen.  Try connecting a different computer to it.

Comment: The only thing is, he's connecting all of his computers to a wireless router.  So unless the router is having problems with the modem, I don't see how a bad NIC could cause the issue.

Comment: @MBraedley: Good point; I missed that - but it could still be the connection between the modem and router, which would be harder to eliminate as a possibility.

Comment: One way to test it would be to connect one of the laptops to the modem with a cable, and if it still drops the connection, then it's likely the modem or line, not the router.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue make sure your router and cable modem is not placed on metal stuff and they both are not heating up. Try to change their position very often and see if the problem still persists.

Comment: They are not heated and they are placed on a wooden table - no metal.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at [that router on google](http://www.google.com/products?q=Edimax%20BR-6226n&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N&hl=en&tab=wf) shows me it's worth around $50 brand new.

That is a cheap router, you get what you pay for it.

In my experience, every time the fix to a router problem is just a reset it tells me the router have not enough hardware to handle the network traffic.

That's about it.